# TypeORM one-to-many relation using Entity Schema

Tags: node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have two entities Projects & Orders. I want to have One-to-Many Orders in Projects and Many-to-One project in Orders.

Many-to-one side is working fine.

When I try to add One-to-Many in Project entity and try to fetch all, I get following error:

```
"Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined"
```

**Project Entity**

```
const { EntitySchema } = require('typeorm');
const { BaseRelations, BaseColumns } = require('../BaseEntity');

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Project',    
  columns: {
    ...BaseColumns,
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
    }
  },
  relations: {
    ...BaseRelations,
    orders: {
      type: 'one-to-many',
      target: 'Order',
      cascade: true,
    },
  },
});
```

**Order Entity**

```
const { EntitySchema } = require('typeorm');

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Order',
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
      name: 'name',
    },
  },
  relations: {
    project: {
      type: 'many-to-one',
      target: 'Project',
      joinColumn: {
        name: 'project_id',
      },
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone who is facing the similar issue. You will need to define `inverseSide` in both entities schema. `inverseSide` value should be the relation name defined in the entity on the other side of relation.

So for my entities above I will need to make the following changes:

Project Entity:

```
const { EntitySchema } = require('typeorm');
const { BaseRelations, BaseColumns } = require('../BaseEntity');

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Project',    
  columns: {
    ...BaseColumns,
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
    }
  },
  relations: {
    ...BaseRelations,
    orders: {
      type: 'one-to-many',
      target: 'Order',
      cascade: true,
      inverseSide: 'project' // Note that this is relation name, not the entity name
    },
  },
});
```

Order Entity:

```
const { EntitySchema } = require('typeorm');

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Order',
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
      name: 'name',
    },
  },
  relations: {
    project: {
      type: 'many-to-one',
      target: 'Project',
      joinColumn: {
        name: 'project_id',
      },
      inverseSide: 'orders' // Note that this is the relation name in project entity, no the entity name Order
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Did this work so that saving the project saved all of its orders? Currently experiencing an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688642/typeorm-one-to-many-many-to-one-javascript) where saving the parent object only saves the first child of the array with cascade set to true.

Comment: yes the cascading did work.