# TypeOrm One-to-Many/Many-to-One Javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron, typeorm

I have a `Week` entity that I would like to save with a one-to-many relationship with the `Day` entity.

**Week Entity**

```
new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Week',
  target: Week,
  columns: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primary: true,
      generated: true,
    },
    startDate: {
      type: 'date',
    },
  },
  relations: {
    days: {
      type: 'one-to-many',
      target: 'Day',
      inverseSide: 'week',
      cascade: true,
    },
  },
});
```

**Day Entity**

```
new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Day',
  target: Day,
  columns: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primary: true,
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
    },
    date: {
      type: 'varchar',
    },
  },
  relations: {
    week: {
      type: 'many-to-one',
      target: 'Week',
      inverseSide: 'day',
    },
  },
});
```

These are my current entities. From my understanding, given a `Week` object with an array of day objects in `week.days` using `cascade = true;` and,

```
await AppDataSource.getRepository('week').save(week)
```

should save the week and its day objects. Instead, only the first day of the `.days` array is being saved.